# Logic of #define (microchip xc8 compiler)

Tags: c, macros, logic, c-preprocessor, pic

I just started learning **C** for pic programming and I was looking at other people's code and at the includes files provided with the compiler, especially the fundamental ones (xc.h, pic.h, pic specific headers...) and I saw this construct (it's found in pic.h)

```
#define __delay_us(x) _delay((unsigned long)((x)*(_XTAL_FREQ/4000000.0)))
```

Naturally it works, but I have problems understanding the underlying logic of it.
As I understand it #define is an "alias maker", you tell the compiler to substitute the code X with Y every time it's encountered in the program. But that's it, simple substitution. Here I see a variable, an input or an argument (x), passed to the substitute but I don't get HOW! If it was for me I would have made a function for this, and I see how useful a construct like that can be, if I find a code where a delay macro is unnecessarily made (maybe because the author didn't know about the native _delay, or because I'm porting code form another compiler) I can simply redefine the (hypothetical!) "wait(200)" to point to the native "_delay(200)". Now the question is anybody can explain to me how this construct works? X is not even declared, wouldn't it be treated as a simple character to substitute and not a value to be passed? 
Would this construct be equivalent?

```
#define wait(x) __delay_us(unsigned long x)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`__delay_us(x)` here is a [function-like macro](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Macro-Arguments.html). Function-like macros allow for more dynamic constants (nice paradox, eh). It works just like a normal macro, but you give them an argument. The argument is then substituted literally into the macro which is then substituted into the code. For example:

```
float y = 12000000.0;
unsigned long delay = __delay_us(y);
```

will be expaned to:

```
float y = 12000000.0;
unsigned long delay = _delay((unsigned long)((y)*(_XTAL_FREQ/4000000.0)));
```

(note `y` instead of `x`)

Be very careful when defining your own function-like macros:

1. The arguments are substituted literally, make sure they only occur once in the macro-body. If someone provides a function-call as argument it could give unwanted results.
2. As you've seen, no type-checking is done at all, as types don't exist in macros.

For more pitfalls: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Macro-Pitfalls.html (although you're not using GCC, it probably still applies)

Comment: Thank you, your explanation was very clear and also thank you for pointing me to how this construct is called and to documents about it

Answer (score 1):

To make sure you understand exactly whats going on, I'd just suggest experimenting with the preprocessor and checking out its output (before compilation, right after preprocessing & subsitutions are done). In GCC you can see the preprocessor output with: `gcc -E filename`.